# XNA Window Resize Invokes LoadContent

Tags: c#, .net, xna

Anytime I resize my XNA Window to the smallest possible resolution (0 pixels high) the program starts invoking LoadContent again which causes my app to crash (since I only want it to load content once). What can I do, is there a way I can stop the user from resizing my window too much (such as setMinimumSize in Java). Or is there another solution?

Thanks,

Comment: This happens in both XNA 3.1 and 4.0.

Comment: It also calls `UnloadContent` - if you wanted to make your game itself more robust.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To stop the user resizing your window too much, set the MinimumSize property on the form associated with the game window.

Add the following references to your project:

```
System.Drawing
System.Windows.Forms
```

Add constants for your desired minimum size:

```
const int MIN_SIZE_X = 300;
const int MIN_SIZE_Y = MIN_SIZE_X;
```

Add the following to your constructor or Initialize function.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Form.FromHandle(Window.Handle).MinimumSize = new System.Drawing.Size(MIN_SIZE_X, MIN_SIZE_Y);
```