# Changing the graphics settings calls `LoadContent`

Tags: c#, graphics, xna, xna-4.0

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705579/xna-window-resize-invokes-loadcontent) may be related.

I have this code in the `Update` method:

```
    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 1024;
        graphics.ApplyChanges();

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
```

Strangely enough, after the `ApplyChanges` line, my `LoadContent` method is called again. This happens over and over again.

Why is this happening, and how can I prevent it?

Comment: Why are you calling `ApplyChanges` every frame?

Comment: Well, I can confirm that this isn't happening on my machine (blank XNA Game project, change called on a key press). Are you hooking up anything special?

Comment: @AndrewRussell This is a simplification of my code, not an exact copy-paste.

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided is actually related assuming `graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight` is 0. You can prevent this from happening by using [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3706052/1710831) provided on the link you provided. Also, you should make sure `graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight` has a value greater than zero before you apply changes.

Answer (score 0):

Normally XNA should do a device *reset* when you call `ApplyChanges`, which does a bunch of DirectX magic to make sure all your textures, etc, stay loaded. (It doesn't call `LoadContent`.)

However, it's possible for the reset to fail for a few obscure reasons. It's possibly due to the [shenanigans you're doing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13695093/165500) during device setup. Or it could just be a flaky driver or something. Or both. When the reset fails, XNA falls-back to re-creating the device from scratch.

Once the device is recreated from scratch, all your textures and other resources are completely gone. The best thing XNA can do now is call your `LoadContent` method and *hope* that your game is robustly coded enough to re-load everything and continue. (Getting your game this robust is a modest amount of effort - it may not be worth it.)

There is no sensible way to prevent this behaviour from happening. I'd first suggest getting your use of `ApplyChanges` [sorted out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13699229/165500) - which includes not calling it every frame! - and see if the problem simply goes away.

Comment: I don't think means to call it every frame - he only downsized the code for brevity. If I recall correctly, this is related to an event based system for changing the resolution that threw the [`InvalidOperationException`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13695093/why-does-changing-the-graphics-setting-after-doing-so-in-the-loadcontent-metho) he mentions in a previous question (can't find the original, must have been deleted). He removed the code to show the exact problem, which is a very good approach IMO.

Comment: Unfortunately that omission changes the meaning of the code quite substantially. I think it would be best to wrap that code in an `if(something)`, so that at least the meaning is preserved. Although, if events are involved, you'd want to be *damn* sure that the conditional is equivalent to the event behaviour. It makes it very difficult to answer questions if important code is missing!

Comment: (Also, I was really hoping for an "I'm not" in response to the comment I made on the original question, before I posted my answer.)